# Cannot get booleans to work on insert using spring boot and postgresql

Tags: json, database, postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot

I'm having some problems working with booleans with spring boot and postgresql. I have a field deleted that is defined as a boolean in both the entity bean and the database table. It looks like on a select throw the rest API I am being returned a JSON char instead of a boolean. On insert whether I try a boolean or a char ( i.e building the body from a response from a query) I get an error.  I am running on OpenJDK 11.PostgreSQL JDBC Driver 42.2.5. Wildflt 15.

I've tried both using char "t" as returned on the select (get) and JSON boolean true. Definition of json boolean I relied on

https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/boolean.html

Here's the table create

```
CREATE TABLE TRANSFER_PARTITIONED_IMAGE (
    TRANSFER_PARTITIONED_IMAGE_ID     INTEGER NOT NULL,
    IMAGE_NAME               VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    REQUESTED_PART_SIZE_MB   INTEGER NOT NULL,
    SIZE_BYTES               INTEGER NOT NULL,
    IMAGE_MD5_HASH           VARCHAR(100),
    NUMBER_PARTITIONS        INTEGER,
    DELETED                  BOOLEAN  NOT NULL
);
```

Here's the insert I used to put a row in the table from the postgresql command line

```
crowbar=> insert into transfer_partitioned_image       
values(45,'foofoobarbarbarbarsnafu',10,10,'aa',10,true);
```

JSON returned on a select. Note it returns a char "t" for the boolean field.

```
 {
   "transferPartitionedImageId": 45,
   "imageName": "foofoobarbarbarbarsnafu",
   "requestedPartSizeMB": 10,
   "sizeBytes": 10,
   "imageMD5Hash": "aa",
   "numberPartitions": 10,
   "deleted": "t"
 }
```

If I try to insert using the "t" for the boolean value I get a server 500 error

```
{
  "timestamp": "2019-10-07T13:48:38.077+0000",
  "message": "could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement",
  "details": "uri=/crowbar/data/rit/transferPartitionedImage"
}
```

from the log file

```
2019-10-07 13:48:38,075 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)     insert
2019-10-07 13:48:38,075 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)     into
2019-10-07 13:48:38,075 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)           transfer_partitioned_image
2019-10-07 13:48:38,075 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)         (deleted, image_md5_hash, image_name, number_partitions, requested_part_size_mb, size_bytes)
2019-10-07 13:48:38,075 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)     values
2019-10-07 13:48:38,075 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)         (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
2019-10-07 13:48:38,076 DEBUG [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (default task-1) could not execute statement [n/a]: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "deleted" is of type boolean but expression is of type character varying
  Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
```

If I try the same thing using a JSON boolean ( tried both an upper case and lower case TRUE)

```
{
  "transferPartitionedImageId": 1111,
  "imageName": "foofoobarfoofoobarsnafusnafu",
  "requestedPartSizeMB": 10,
  "sizeBytes": 10,
  "imageMD5Hash": "aa",
  "numberPartitions": 10,
  "deleted": true
}
```

I get a 400 bad request error

```
Status Code: 400 Bad Request
Connection: keep-alive
Date: Mon, 07 Oct 2019 13:53:13 GMT
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

From the log

```
019-10-07 13:53:13,160 DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver] (default task-1) Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.lang.Character` out of VALUE_TRUE token; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.lang.Character` out of VALUE_TRUE token
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 8, column: 14] (through reference chain: com.ticomgeo.crowbar.data.entity.TransferPartitionedImage["deleted"])]
```

My entity bean definition is shown below

```
Entity Bean definition
@Entity
public class TransferPartitionedImage implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = -3444719649254510891L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer transferPartitionedImageId;
@NotNull
@Size(min = 10, max = 50, message = "Image name must be 10  to 50 characters")
@Column(name = "IMAGE_NAME", nullable = false, length = 50)
private String imageName;
@NotNull
@Column(name = "REQUESTED_PART_SIZE_MB", nullable = false)
private Integer requestedPartSizeMB;
@Column(name = "SIZE_BYTES")
private Integer sizeBytes;
@Column(name = "IMAGE_MD5_HASH")
private String imageMD5Hash;
@Column(name = "NUMBER_PARTITIONS")
private Integer numberPartitions;
@Column (name = "DELETED")
private Boolean deleted;
public Integer getTransferPartitionedImageId() {
    return transferPartitionedImageId;
}
public void setTransferPartitionedImageId(Integer   transferPartitionedImageId) {
    this.transferPartitionedImageId = transferPartitionedImageId;
}
public String getImageName() {
    return imageName;
}
public void setImageName(String imageName) {
    this.imageName = imageName;
}
public Integer getRequestedPartSizeMB() {
    return requestedPartSizeMB;
}
public void setRequestedPartSizeMB(Integer requestedPartSizeMB) {
    this.requestedPartSizeMB = requestedPartSizeMB;
}
public Integer getSizeBytes() {
    return sizeBytes;
}
public void setSizeBytes(Integer sizeBytes) {
    this.sizeBytes = sizeBytes;
}
public String getImageMD5Hash() {
    return imageMD5Hash;
}
public void setImageMD5Hash(String imageMD5Hash) {
    this.imageMD5Hash = imageMD5Hash;
}
public Integer getNumberPartitions() {
    return numberPartitions;
}

public void setNumberPartitions(Integer numberPartitions) {
    this.numberPartitions = numberPartitions;
}
public Boolean getDeleted() {
    return deleted;
}
public void setDeleted(Boolean deleted) {
    this.deleted = deleted;
}
public Boolean isDeleted() {
    return deleted ;
}
```

I would have expected the select to have returned a JSON boolen i.e.
   deleted : true
Instead of a char "t". I also would have expected that pasting an example of what was returned on a select into the body of a post with a new primary key to have worked on an insert.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was related to how I was deploying the war file in the container. In an earlier version the field was a char. I modified the entity bean to make it a Boolean and copied the war file into the wildfly instance's deployment directory. Apparently the JPA annotations are not updated in that case so the change to the Entity bean was not deployed. Restarting the wildfly instance eliminated the issue without any code changes.

Answer (score -1):

Try with annotation

```
@GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
```